# ImportError: No module named mandrill

Tags: python, macos, mandrill

I installed mandrill using pip:

```
(venv)Jhons-MacBook-Pro:venv jhonjairoroa87$ pip install mandrill
```

I got this result:

```
Downloading/unpacking mandrill
Downloading mandrill-1.0.57.tar.gz
Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/x3/st96cn215h915kqwlcrmtspw0000gn/T/pip_build_jhonjairoroa87/mandrill/setup.py) egg_info for package mandrill
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=0.13.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mandrill)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docopt==0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mandrill)
Installing collected packages: mandrill
Running setup.py install for mandrill
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/mandrill from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/sendmail.mandrill from 644 to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/mandrill to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/sendmail.mandrill to 755
Successfully installed mandrill
Cleaning up...
```

But when I try to use it, fails:

```
(venv)Jhons-MacBook-Pro:venv jhonjairoroa87$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mandrill
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mandrill
>>> 
>>> import sendmail.mandrill
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sendmail.mandrill
```

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: Try `import sendmail.mandrill`

Comment: No, @BhargavRao Rao. I only have Python 2.7 installed.

Comment: @sakamisiniz, I tried it and still I get no module named error (Updated post)

Comment: OK. I faced this problem when I had both versions installed, Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I uninstalled it using

```
pip uninstall mandrill
```

and reinstalled it using the python -m option:

```
sudo python -m pip install mandrill
```

Now it works perfectly.

```
(venv)Jhons-MacBook-Pro:python_mandrill jhonjairoroa87$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mandrill
>>>
```